# Make checkboxes select-able one at a time like radio-buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for some help making checkboxes behave like radio-buttons in that one in a group can only be selected at a time with jQuery.

First, why not use radio-buttons ? Because I want these forms of input to also be un-select-able / un-check-able so that the potential exists that none of them can be checked.

So I have 9 input type checkbox that are grouped in 3 groups of 3, not in forms, just grouped by the fact that those 3 have the same value to the name attribute.

All 9 checkboxes have the class of .secondary-input but only 3 have the name of one, then the next 3 a name of two, and the last three a name of three.

What I am trying to accomplish is that only one of the group is checked at a time and that one can be unchecked so that none in the group are checked.

I would greatly appreciate all and any help in achieving this.

I found a JSFiddle like this, but the jQuery didn't work with my system of groups by the name attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they all have the same name, you can just uncheck the other ones with the same name attribute:

```
$(":checkbox").on('change', function () {
    $('[name="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F2JPP/

Comment: I second that, very nice solution. Excellent jQuery. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the specifics of this language, but can you loop through all your checkbox items and toggle any that are on and ought to be off? Pseudo code:

```
for checkbox in checkboxes:
    if checkbox.checked == true %% checkbox != selectedCheckbox:
        checkbox.toggle
```